# Can no longer copy paste since installing High Sierra

Tags: macos-high-sierra

This apply to all the applications I've tested.
Command V / Command C doesn't work.  Nor does using the Edit -> Copy/Paste

The only suggestions I found was to boot in safe mode, but this didn't resolve the problem.